# How to pass a unique id as a prop to another component

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a to-do in react to practice certain concepts, and I'm currently trying to have my list items as a separate component to help make the state iteration cleaner with having check boxes and add/remove buttons for each item on the list.

When iterating over the state to create each list item, I am trying to pass the id of each item to the list in order to have a unique id for each li element as requested by react. My code is currently as follows:

App.js

```
function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([ 

  ])

  const addItem = (item) => {
    if(item === '') {return}
    setItems([...items, { item, id: uuid() }])
  }

  return (
    <Layout>
      <div>
        <h1>To-Do</h1>
        <Input addItem={addItem}/>
        <ul>
          {items.map(i => (
            <ListItem 
              id={i.id}>
                {i.item}
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

ListItem.js

```
const ListItem = (props) => {
    return (
        <li key={props.id}>{props.children}</li>
    )
}
```

I am using react-uuid to create the unique id's. The id's are showing properly when listed out from the state, so they are there. But they aren't passing correctly as a prop from App.js to ListItem.js for some reason. When I add new items to the list, I receive the "Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop."

Any ideas why this error is happening?

Comment: Add the key in the map.. `<ListItem key={i.id} ...>`

Comment: Ahhh, so I don't need to have the key as a property of the li element in the ListItem component, I can put the key directly on the component call in the App.js file and it will know that should be added to each li created that way?

Comment: Sort of. The `li` isn't the child in the list that react is complaining about.  It's the `ListItem` that needs the key.

Comment: Ok cool, that makes sense. Thanks for clearing that up for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React uses keys in order to uniquely identify **siblings** in a list. Why you might ask? Because React will try to update the DOM as little as possible with only the elements that have been changed / added / removed.
See more details in the [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#recursing-on-children).

So whenever you use map, make sure to add keys:

```
items.map(i => <ListItem key={i.id} />);
```

No need to add a key when implementing ListItem.